# UPDATE a field with a value from another table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I need to update a field with a value from another table in MySQL, using Python Connector (not that important though). I need to select a value from one table based on a matching criteria and insert the extracted column back into the previous table based on the same matching criteria.

I have the following, which doesn't work of cource.

```
for match_field in list:
        cursor_importer.execute(UPDATE table1 SET table1_field = 
             (SELECT field_new FROM table2 WHERE match_field = %s) 
             WHERE match_field = %s LIMIT 1,
             (match_field, match_field ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE` with `JOINS`.

Below is an example in MySQL:

```
UPDATE table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.match_field = b.match_field
SET a.table1_field = b.field_new
WHERE a.match_field = 'filter criteria'
```